# Internal Server Error on cpannel in node js

Tags: node.js, deployment, dependencies, cpanel, internal-server-error

i am kinda new in deployment of nodejs on c Pannel.
I installed node js on c pannel and upload my code to c pannel. Only the default router work like

```
`app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  return res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            res: "Api is working",
            data: null
        });
    
});`
```

this route works only

```
`app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  return res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            res: "Api is working",
            data: null
        });
    
});`
```

Only this route works, even if i user

```
`app.get('/check', (req,res)=>{
  return res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            res: "Api is working",
            data: null
        });
    
});`
```

it give me internal server error 500
and all other routes as well giving me Internal server error 500
`// Auth Routes app.use('/api/auth', require('./Routes/Auth')); // Role Routes app.use('/api/role', require('./Routes/Roles'))`

My Code Structure
[image]

Comment: the best thing to do is to check the Apache log on the server at /etc/apache2/logs/error_log to see what the webserver itself is reporting. and share with us what log error

Comment: /etc/apache2/logs/error_log  There is nothing in my server when i search this, but some other folders are in etc folder ,

Comment: did you run Npm install command and specifiy in your `package.json` main entry is `app.js` ?

Comment: i face the same issue, how you solved it by the way?